# webBrowser control: how to navigate other pages and fill form after successfully login

Tags: c#, browser

how can i fill multipages form using webBrowser control?
i should change webBrowser.Navigate("url") but how?
Can someone post some code, please?
Thanks a lot!
Barbara

Answer (score 0):

Actually I would recommend using [WatiN](http://watin.org/) for such operations - it should be easier.
(I guess you want to debug your application for massive use - or maybe create some bot or whatever)

Comment: `var browser = new IE(webpagestring); IE.browser.TextField("SearchValue").Type("hey); IE.Button("Send").Click();`